# Show that a set $K$ cofinal in a directed set $J$ is also a directed set

Tags: general-topology

$J$ directed means that for all pairs $a,b$ in $J, \exists c$ s.t. $a,b<c$ and $K$ is cofinal in $J$ so for each $j \in J$, $\exists d \in K$ such that $j<d$.

I am struggling with how to prove this.  I have tried by contradiction (there exists $x,y \in K$ such that  $\forall z \in K$ such that $x,y<z$), but don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x, y \in K \subseteq J$, where $K$ is cofinal in $J$. Then because $J$ is directed, there is $z \in J$ such that $x, y \leq z$. Since $K$ is cofinal, there is $w \in K$ with $z \leq w$. So we have $x,y \leq z \leq w$ and we conclude that $K$ itself is directed.

Comment: Wow that was easy.  I completely forgot $K \subset J$...oops